# Foreign Key/DBRef in Spring Data Firestore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, spring-data

I have 2 entities:
1- User:

```
@Document(collectionName = CollectionConstants.USER_COLLECTION)
public class User {
  @DocumentId
  protected String id;

  private String username;
}
```

2- Contest:

```
@Document(collectionName = CollectionConstants.CONTEST_COLLECTION)
public class Contest {
  private List<User> contestants;
}
```

How can I save only the ID of the user (whether it's a list of users, or a single user) in the database while letting Spring Data manage that automatically?

I'm actually looking for an alternative for the following:

- Spring Data JPA: `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`
- Spring Data MongoDB: `@DBRef`

Answer (score -1):

I have checked in the [Spring Cloud GCP for Firestore](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.M1/#_cloud_firestore), and it states:

> The starter automatically configures and registers a Firestore bean in the Spring application context. To start using it, simply use the `@Autowired` annotation.

```
@Autowired
Firestore firestore;

void writeDocumentFromObject() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // Add document data with id "joe" using a custom User class
    User data = new User("Joe",
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Phone(12345, PhoneType.CELL),
                    new Phone(54321, PhoneType.WORK)));

    // .get() blocks on response
    WriteResult writeResult = this.firestore.document("users/joe").set(data).get();

    LOGGER.info("Update time: " + writeResult.getUpdateTime());
}

User readDocumentToObject() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> documentFuture =
                this.firestore.document("users/joe").get();

        User user = documentFuture.get().toObject(User.class);

        LOGGER.info("read: " + user);

        return user;
}
```

There is sample https://github.com/spring-cloud-gcp/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-firestore-sample

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it's not actually related to the question. The question states that I'm looking for an alternative to @DBRef/ManyToOne in Spring Data Firestore